# Test if char array contains some letters

Tags: java, boolean-logic

I have a `char[]` that must be comprised of the letters :  `'R', 'B', 'O', 'V', 'J', 'F', 'I', 'N'`. I must check if the array contains only these letters and if not, I need to reintroduce the letters till it contains the correct letters.

I did this by a method (which is not working):

```
boolean validation=false;
if (choixJoueur.length != 4) {
    validation=false;
} else {
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       if (choixJoueur[i] != 'R' || choixJoueur[i] != 'B'
                || choixJoueur[i] != 'O' || choixJoueur[i] != 'V'
                || choixJoueur[i] != 'J' || choixJoueur[i] != 'F'
                || choixJoueur[i] != 'I' || choixJoueur[i] != 'N')) {
            validation=false;

        } else
            validation=true;
    }
}
```

If I test it with `RBVD` the validation is (correctly) calculated as `false`, but if I try `RBVO` the validation is (incorrectly) `false` too.

Comment: dont chain together `if` clauses, use a `switch` statement

Comment: Can you show me one character for which `choixJoueur[i] != 'R' || choixJoueur[i] != 'B'` condition would be evaluated to `false`? (helper question: when `foo || bar` expression will be evaluated to `false`? What value would `foo` and `bar` need to take?)

Comment: Also, think about what happens on each iteration of the `for` loop, and then when it's finished (hint: `validation` is getting assigned on each iteration). does it need to contain all of the letters or just one?

Comment: Arrays are not resizable in Java; you probably want to use a `Collection` of some sort, and in your case a `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (choixJoueur[i] != 'R' || choixJoueur[i] != 'B'
            || choixJoueur[i] != 'O' || choixJoueur[i] != 'V'
            || choixJoueur[i] != 'J' || choixJoueur[i] != 'F'
            || choixJoueur[i] != 'I' || choixJoueur[i] != 'N')) {
        validation=false;

    }else
        validation=true;
}
```

Let's debug your code:

Your input for example: `RBVD` then:

```
R != R is false but R != B is true so validation = false
B != R is true so validation = false
V != R is true so validation = false
D != R is true so validation = false
```

You remain with false the same goes with your second input.

You might want to change `||` for `&&` on your `if` validations to validate all of the possibilities.

Also, in case the validation is false, you might want to `break` the `for-loop` :) (Or that's my guess)

If changed to `&&` this would be the debug:

```
R != R is false so validation = true
B != R is true but B != B is false so validation = true
V != R is true but V != V is false so validation = true
D != R is true and D is different from all of the rest of letters, so validation = false
```

On the other hand with `RBVO`

```
R != R is false so validation = true
B != R is true but B != B is false so validation = true
V != R is true but V != V is false so validation = true
O != R is true but O != O is false so validation = true
```

After all of that your `if` statement should be:

```
if (choixJoueur[i] != 'R' && choixJoueur[i] != 'B'
            && choixJoueur[i] != 'O' && choixJoueur[i] != 'V'
            && choixJoueur[i] != 'J' && choixJoueur[i] != 'F'
            && choixJoueur[i] != 'I' && choixJoueur[i] != 'N')) {
        validation=false;
        break; //because I guess if it contains any of the letters the validation fails, if you don't and the next letter is a valid one it will override validation to true.

    }else
        validation=true;
}
```

Also you can change it to:

```
boolean validate = true;
```

and remove the `else` statement inside your `for-loop`. But still take into consideration the `break` statement since it will prevent the program from doing more operations when it knows it's an invalid input from the moment it finds it's invalid (such as on 1st letter or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Frakcool is right about the first part. You want to check that a character {is not R, AND it is not B, AND it is not O, AND ...}. Currently, you are checking if an individual character {is not R, OR is not B, OR is not O, OR ...}. This doesn't work because every character in existence will be either not R or not B.

You also have another problem which is that you are only effectively checking if the last character is one of those characters because for every character you reset the value of 'validation' without taking into consideration a past failure. In other words, if the first letter failed but the last letter passed, you just set validation to true even though it should be false. Instead, it's best to just start with true and set it to false whenever a failure condition is encountered, without ever setting it to true again.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        char[] choixJoueur = { 'R', 'B', 'V', 'O' };

        boolean validation = true;

        if (choixJoueur.length != 4)
            validation = false;
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (choixJoueur[i] != 'R' && choixJoueur[i] != 'B'
                        && choixJoueur[i] != 'O' && choixJoueur[i] != 'V'
                        && choixJoueur[i] != 'J' && choixJoueur[i] != 'F'
                        && choixJoueur[i] != 'I' && choixJoueur[i] != 'N')
                {
                    validation = false;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(validation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the logic; you should be using `&&` (rather than `||`) between your conditions (every character is *not* equal to at least one of the tested chars).

But you can simplify your code considerably by using regex, which does it all in one line:

```
boolean validation = new String(choixJoueur).matches("[RBOVJFIN]{4}");
```

If you want to also assert that no character is used more than once:

```
boolean validation = new String(choixJoueur).matches("((?!(.).*\\1)[RBOVJFIN]){4}");
```